# iOS How to send cell data to another VC use parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How i can send data from my table view cell, to another VC when in tap on cell.

My code for fetch data from DB:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! cellRequestsTVC

    let good = data[indexPath.row]
    name = good["username"] as! String
    cell.userNameLable.text = "@\(name)"

    area = good["place"] as! String
    cell.areaLable.text = "\(area)"

    cell.descriptionLable.text = good["description"] as? String
    cell.priorityLable.text = "Priority " + ((good["priority"] as? Int)?.description)!

    let imageProblems = good["image"] as? PFFile
    imageProblems?.getDataInBackground{ (imageData, error)in
        if imageData != nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.problemImage.image = image
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

It's working perfect. But now my target open data from cell in another VC.
Example:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBsov.gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement **UITableViewDelegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let good = data[indexPath.row]
// Here you can either perform a segue or push view controller to UINavigationController

//Push View controller 

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : DetailViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController
    vc.sharedData = data // here you pass data
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

}
```

In `DetailViewController` create object of data with required type

```
var sharedData : [String : Any]! // Take optional variable if object can be nil & here assuming data contains object of type [String : Any]
```

You can look the documentation here
[UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

Comment: Cannot assign value of type '[PFObject]' to type '[String : Any]!'

Comment: Try this
var sharedData : [PFObject]?

Comment: Like var sharedData = [PFObject]() it's working, but how i can put data for example in Label?

Comment: @BestMoments `label.text = sharedData["username"] as! String` It is apprx same as like as you have done in the `cellForRow`

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[PFObject]' with an index of type 'String'